# Installing several different flavours of Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, multiple-desktops

I know it used to be possible to install several different flavours of Ubuntu into the same Ubuntu base.  I could log out of flavour 1 and log back into Flavour 2, and so on
I have forgotten how to do this :-(
Please advise.

Comment: For testing I would use VirtualBox

Comment: That is most helpful.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can install multiple desktops on a base system.

The system I'm replying to you on is originally a *artful* (17.10) Ubuntu desktop install, on which I added `lubuntu-desktop`, `xubuntu-desktop` & `ubuntu-mate-desktop`. It's been upgraded every six months (I don't remain on LTS or *long-term-support* releases).

I have since removed `ubuntu-mate-desktop` (because of disk space issues; I used it least).

Take note:

- On adding the **second** desktop I would not expect any issues.
- On adding the **third** desktop there is a minor chance of issues.
- On adding the **fourth** desktop there is a substantial risk of issues.
- On adding the **fifth** desktop, issues are to be expected.

I installed my 4 (GNOME, XFCE, LXDE [now LXQt] & MATE) many times in different orders before I calculated the best order without issues, then formatted the system and installed them for real (*and it's still running now, where I'm replying from*).

I also wanted KDE (or `kubuntu-desktop`) but decided that was too much, the problems got annoying.

It's not just the desktops, but also the order they are added.

The above is from my experience, as a multiple-desktop user for over a decade on Ubuntu (longer on Debian).

Comment: THE answer I was seeking PLUS advice about problems.  Great.

Comment: As you add more desktops, the issues becomes more severe. Once you have 3+ you'll find changes you make on one can have unintended consequences on others, esp. with the appearance (*don't forget changes to a GTK desktop will likely impact all GTK desktops, likewise Qt impacting other Qt desktops*) and you need to use themes/icons/etc in work in all... ie. You'll find you aren't changing display configs much once its working esp. if you have 4+ desktops.   I didn't mention the busy & sometimes confusing menus etc..  I love it though; I can select in the morning how my PC will look for the day.

Answer (score 1):

You can install different desktops from the terminal e.g.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop xubuntu-desktop
```

You can choose which one to use when you log in.

Comment: Problem was I had forgotten I had to get desktops from the terminal NOT from a mirror.:-(  Thanks to everyone!