# How best to bring a broken desktop (MATE) back?

Tags: login, mate

At power-up, the greeter window provides for each of my 4 login ID's these desktops:  Gnome, Gnome Classic, Ubuntu, Ubuntu w/ Wayland, MATE, Budgie, KDE/Plasma, and a few others.

Something about the MATE desktop is broken to the extent all I get is a background image and a moving mouse cursor.

No clicking or keystrokes (shy of <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, which brings up a console login) do anything.

What is the suggested way to repair MATE?   Thx.

Comment: You've not provided your OS/release details; not been very specific with details. I'm a lover of multi-desktop boxes (or *bloated* systems) but I ensure I install everything I usually install the whole *flavor* desktop as installing less than has in my experience meant the results are release specific (*and you've not provided yours*).  What exactly you have installed (*given what you've provided*) to me matters, as beyond 3 desktops which you appear to have, issues can be expected which vary on what is installed + the order it was installed; which you didn't specify.

Comment: Sorry, it's Ubuntu 20.04...  First installed desktop was Gnome, then MATE, then KDE/Plasma, then Budgie, and finally XFCE4.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing several different flavours of Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295149/installing-several-different-flavours-of-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: @guiverc:  Unfortunately that link is focused on installing.  Which I have done w/o problem.  The OP topic is about repairing a particular desktop that appears broken.  Would you know of troubleshooting steps or suggestions in that area?

Comment: In my opinion that link describes your problem; in you have Ubuntu Desktop; added Kubuntu DE Ubuntu Budgie DE & finally Xubuntu DE (*though your question also mentions Ubuntu-MATE desktop too*). Fixing the issues I mentioned is very specific & likely relates (*in my experience*) to interactions of the *flavor* desktops & your settings. If you had Ubuntu Desktop & added Ubuntu MATE alone you'd have no issues with setup as its interaction between many you have, and only those with all those *flavors* installed (*and in the order you used*) are likely to experience issues you have & provide clues

Comment: I also said to be specific on details; to install KDE Plasma did you install `kubuntu-desktop` or something else? ie. specifics. When multi-desktop setups are installed (esp. if >3) specific details really matter, and that can include the icons/themes/etc used on each (as they all ~interact with GTK/Qt themes directly or indirectly due to the multitude of apps we'll have installed).  You can influence one DE's looks/behavior by making changes in others (*one of reasons why multi-desktop installs aren't great for newbies; so all DEs must be setup in ways that won't be problems with others*).

Comment: I think I used kubuntu-desktop (as the label for a package) to install KDE/Plasma.     I'm OK with less DE's. The impetus behind having multiple DE's, was to chase an elusive problem that had arisen with a critical application I need to run, 'MuseScore'.  Just last night I found the Budgie DE seems to allow MuseScore to run w/o problem.  Which is curious & surprising to me.  I'd be OK with simply de-installing MATE (if that's possible).  I get reluctant with removing -whatever- when Synaptic warns it has to remove what sounds like packages I need, as dependent on removal of XX or YY.